# Connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I need to connect to an SQL database to see how many records it is holding. I cannot access phpmyadmin and no one seems to know the host name or port. All I have is the username and database name.

How can I find the information I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find someone, anyone, who can connect to the database you need to connect to.

Then you can examine their setup - and connect to the same place.

Otherwise, you're into port-scanning across the machines in your network.  Beware of intrusion detection systems.  Be clever about it.  And scan your machine(s) first.

Answer (score 1):

If it's on the same computer that you are working on, then the hostname is `localhost` and the port is default (3306).

Answer (score 1):

...or if you have terminal/console access to the machine the database is running on, run the command:

```
mysql -u<user> -p<password> -d<database>
```

to log on to the database.

Answer (score 0):

if it is on your network you can scan for the default SQL port that Mikhail has referred to.